On writing integration on Riemannian submanifolds in terms of exponential map
I have a basic question about integrating (restriction of) functions to a Riemannian submanifold. Particularly, given a Riemannian manifold $M$, an embedded Riemannian submanifold $N \subseteq M$, and a function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we know the meaning of
$$\int\limits_{N} f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}\mu_N \left( x \right),$$
where, $\mathrm{d}\mu_N$ is the measure given by the induced Riemannian metric on $N$. Now, suppose in addition that $N$ is determined by the exponential map at a certain point in $N$. That is, suppose there is some $u \in N$ such that for all $x \in N$, there is a unique $x' \in T_uN$ (the tangent space of $N$ at $u$) such that $x = \exp_u \left( x' \right)$. My question is whether one can write
$$\int\limits_{N} f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}\mu_N \left( x \right) = \int\limits_{T_uN} f \left( \exp_u \left( x' \right) \right) \mathrm{d}x',$$
where, $\mathrm{d}x'$ is the Lebesgue measure on the (Euclidean) space $T_uN$?
My initial intuition is no! I believe that has to be some other factor (some "Jacobian") that should come into picture. However, I am not sure about this. Any insights into the matter are appericable!

Evidently, you’re not using the pushforward measure to account for the change of measure scales. Once you do so, it’ll be correct.

Will the pushforward be $|\det (D\exp_u (x'))|$? This should be the precise Jacobian, isn't it?

For the Lebesgue measure -- it sure will be the multiplication factor, yes. For the most generic case of a measure, you would need to be much more accurate.

@EgorLarionov It is the pullback measure, not the pushforward.

@OP The determinant is that of a linear map between two distinct spaces so it has no intrinsic sense as it is. You should specify in which bases it is considered. Here, it must be taken with respect to orthonormal bases on both spaces.

@Didier, absolutely correct. My bad.

The answer is no, and the reason appears if you write properly what it means that "$N$ is determined by the exponential map".
In rigorous terms, you are asking the exponential map $\exp_x$ at a point $x$ to be a diffeomorphism from $T_xN$ to $N$.
Such a point $x$ is called a pole.
Note that this has nothing to do with $N$ being a submanifold of any ambient manifold.
In a general setting, if $\varphi \colon X \to Y$ is a diffeomorphism and if $\omega$ is a volume form on $Y$, then $\varphi^* \omega$ is a volume form on $X$, and for any $\omega$-integrable function $f \colon Y \to \Bbb R$, one has
$$
\int_Y f \, \omega = \int_X (f\circ \varphi) \, \varphi^*\omega.
$$
Hence, if $\exp_x \colon T_xN \to N$ is a diffeomorphism, and if $\mu_N$ is the Riemannian volume form associated to the considered Riemannian metric on $N$, one has, for any integrable function $f \colon N \to \Bbb R$, that
$$
\int_N f \,\mu_N = \int_{T_xN} (f\circ \exp_x) \, \exp_x^* \mu_N.
$$
Since $T_xN$ is endowed with an Euclidean structure via the said Riemannian metric, it has a canonical Lebesgue measure, say $\mathrm{d}\lambda$.
Then $\exp_x^* \mu_N$ has a density with respect to $\mathrm{d} \lambda$, which is given by the absolute value of the determinant of $\mathrm{d}\exp_x(x') \colon T_xN \to T_{x'}N$, which is taken with respect to orthonormal bases of $T_xN$ and $T_{\exp_x(x')}N$.
One then obtains the formula
$$
\int_N f\,\mu_N = \int_{T_xN} (f\circ \exp_x(x')) \, |\det (\mathrm{d}\exp_x(x'))| \, \mathrm{d}\lambda(x').
$$
